# Using the -M to create database migration file on PHPstorn

Tags: php, laravel

I run the command: `composer dump-autoload` and then `php artisan make:model User -m`

I get: `Model already exists!`

But I can’t find it in migration file... Nor anywhere in folder.

How can I find it? Or how can I create database using -M?

Answer (score 2):

This command

```
php artisan make:model User -m
```

asks laravel to do **two** commands at once, which is the [`make:model`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#defining-models) command, and [`make:migration`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#generating-migrations) command. So it should actually creates

- `app/User.php`, and also
- `database\migrations\2018_02_121212_create_users_table.php`

But by default, after you initialized a Laravel project, it should have already included one `app/User.php`, and of course, collision occurs, so error "Model already exist!" emitted.

---

To create just a migration file, call this instead:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

To create just a model file, call this:

```
php artisan make:model User
```